# Can a bot send messages automatically to a group without user interaction?

Tags: telegram-bot

I would like my bot to write updates in the group, without waiting for an update to arrive. Is that something possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! You just need to make a call to the [sendMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage) method and specify the group id.

[image]

**How to get your group id?** Just send a random message in the group and extract the group id from the update object.

Comment: Actually, after bot was added to the group chat it should receive at least one update already (that it was added to the group), that's how you can get group_id value.